# Showing the next row(Which is hidden) on click of the previous row in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have a html data table in which we have alternate rows.One row with status SHOW and another row with status DONE. For example,

```
<table ng-repeat="item in dataSet| ng-hide="item.Status == 'DONE')"><tr><td ng-click ="showDoneRow();">{{item.PrimaryKey}}</td><td>{{item.Status}}</td></tr></table>
```

Now on click of PrimaryKey of row with Status SHOW we need to ng-show the next row with Status DONE. Remember the row with status DONE is hidden already.

Please can any one provide me any solution on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first is that, you have repeat at a wrong place, you are repeating a table where as you should repeat a row. and then write ng-hide separate from ng-repeat

```
<table ng-repeat="| )">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in dataSet" ng-init="item.display = item.Status !== 'DONE'" ng-show="item.display">
    <td ng-click="dataSet[$index+1].display=true">{{item.PrimaryKey}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Status}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and check the ng-click, set ng-show.
using ng-init i created a new property display which decides whether to show/hide the item.
and then on click took the next item index and set its display property to true

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish. It Worked as smooth as Amul butter... :)